# Simple CSS Grid works in FF but not Chrome

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a 1 column 2 row grid. The 2nd row should take all available space. The following seems to work in FF58 but fails in Chrome 63. Is there an error in the code?

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="app-hdr"></div>
  <div id="app-body"></div>
</div>

html, body, #app {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#app {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px auto;   
    grid-template-columns: auto;     
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header"
        "content";
    background: #F00;
}
#app-hdr{
    grid-area: header;
    background: #AAA;
}
#app-body{
    grid-area: content;
    background: #666;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wog9uhud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions is nearly there. Try changing to `grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr`.

https://jsfiddle.net/wog9uhud/1/

Comment: Thank you. So...auto sets the size large enough to accommodate items but not take all space I guess.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows#Values) your guess is absolutely right :)

Comment: Per the spec, `auto` [should take all available space](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#algo-stretch) if `align-content` behaves as `stretch` (that id does by default), unless there is any `fr`-sized track in the same dimension. And it does, if you replace `min-height` with `height` in the example. Looks much like a bug in Chrome.